# Reverse ordered list for jquery submitted comments

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I have one more question lol. I am using a script that allows users to submit comments through jquery ajax, however when they are submitted, the submitted comments submit at the bottom of the other comments which are sorted in descending order (newest on top) when the page first loads (due to mysql query). Is there a way to make it submit on top through some sort of sorting javascript function?

```
  function prepare(response) {
      var d = new Date();
      count++;
      d.setTime(response.time*1000);

      var mytime = d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds();
      var string = '<li class="shoutbox-list" id="list-'+count+'">'
          + '<span class="date">'+mytime+'</span>'
          + '<span class="shoutbox-list-nick"><a href="statistics.php?user='+response.user+'">'+response.user+'</a>:</span>'
          + '<span class="msg">'+response.message+'</span>'
          +'</li>';

      return string;
    }
   function success(response, status)  { 
          if(status == 'success') {
            lastTime = response.time;
            $('#daddy-shoutbox-list').append(prepare(response));
            $('input[name=message]').attr('value', '').focus();
            $('#list-'+count).fadeIn('slow');
            timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
          }
        }
  <div id="daddy-shoutbox">

    <ol id="daddy-shoutbox-list"></ol>


                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend) instead of `append()`.

```
$('#daddy-shoutbox-list').prepend(prepare(response));
```

Comment: Wow I did not even know that function existed. I think I have to brush up on my jquery knowledge. Thanks a lot for your help man. Really appreciate it.